# QueryDSL with Lob Field

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, querydsl

I've an entity class with lob field called RAW (eclipselink JPA provider and sql server), also I'm using querydsl to query to database. But I've this problem...

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
Error Code: 421
Call: SELECT DISTINCT ID, ALTA, ANIO, FECHARECEPCION, INSTITUCION, MES, RAW, VERSION FROM ARCHIVO WHERE (FECHARECEPCION BETWEEN ? AND ?)
    bind => [2013-01-01 00:00:00.0, 2014-01-31 23:59:59.0]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Archivo sql="SELECT DISTINCT ID, ALTA, ANIO, FECHARECEPCION, INSTITUCION, MES, RAW, VERSION FROM ARCHIVO WHERE (FECHARECEPCION BETWEEN ? AND ?)")
```

Any suggestions?

The query is

```
    QArchivo archivo = QArchivo.archivo;
    JPAQuery query = from(archivo); 

    query.where(archivo.institucion.eq(institucion));   
    query.where(archivo.fechaRecepcion.between(fechaInicio, fechaTermino));

    List<Archivo> resultado = query.list(archivo);

    return resultado;
```

Comment: How does the Querydsl query look like?

Comment: I update questions with query...

Comment: clearly the problem is due to lob field and distinct statement...

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that it is using a DISTINCT when you called list() not listDistinct(), and seemed to not have called distinct().  Double check that you are not calling distinct() anywhere.  DISTINCT in normally only used with joins, so since you are not using any, it is very odd that it is used.

You could also try the same query through JPQL or the Criteria API, it should not use DISTINCT unless to specify it.

If you want to use DISTINCT and have a LOB, then you cannot select the LOB.  You can either put the LOB in its own table and reference it through a OneToOne, or make its fetch=LAZY.

You can also reword the query to use a sub-select so that the distinct in only in the sub-select.

i.e.

```
Select a from Archivo a where exists (select a2 from Archivo a2 where ... and a = a2))
```